# Outlook email template completely broken

Tags: email, outlook, html-table

This is the code that is broken in outlook 2013 and 2010 works fine in 2003 and everything else. I am wondering what might be causing the issue. The page is just white and I cant find any of the email template in litmus. If anyone could help that would be great.

```
   <!-- Wrapper 2 (Header) -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">

<!-- 1px Height Border -->
<table class="fullWidth" width="740" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="1" bgcolor="#dedede"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- Mobile Wrapper -->
<table width="100%" height="300" class="fullWidth" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="100%" bgcolor="f6f6f6" background="beachBg.png" style="background-size: 100%; background-position-y: -100px;">
<a href="http://www.something.com">
<div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:740px;height:300px;">
<v:fill type="tile" src="beachBg.png" color="#000000" />
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
<table table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="scaleForMobile" height="300">
<tr align="right" class="socialNav">
<td width="100%">
<table width="35" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="clearing">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="375" valign="top">
<a href="http://www.test.com/blog/feed"><img alt="rss" src="rss.png"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<table width="35" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="clearing">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="375" valign="top">
<a href=""><img alt="vimeo" src="vimeo.png"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<table width="35" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="clearing">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="50" valign="top">
<a href="http://instagram.com/"><img alt="instagram" src="instagram.png"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<table width="35" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="clearing">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="375" valign="top">
<a href="http://twitter.com/"><img alt="tumblr" src="tumblr.png"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<table width="35" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="clearing">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="375" valign="top">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/"><img alt="youtube" src="youtube.png"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<table width="35" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="clearing">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="375" valign="top">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img alt="facebook" src="facebook.png"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<table width="35" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="clearing">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="375" valign="top">
<a href="https://ca.linkedin.com/company/."><img alt="linkedin" src="linkedin.png"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>


</tr>


<tr class="beachLogo">
<td style="width:740;" ><img style="margin-left:80px;" src="beachLogo.png"></td>
<td width="400"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>

</div>

</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table><!-- End Header -->

</td>
</tr>
</table><!-- End Mobile Wrapper -->



<!-- Space -->
<table bgcolor="ffffff" width="740" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobileCenter">
<tr>
<td width="740" height="0">
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table><!-- End Wrapper 2 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of syntax issues I'm seeing.

1. `<a href="http://www.something.com">` is missing a closing tag.
2. You probably shouldn't be wrapping everything in just 1 `<a>` tag like that.
3. The `</tr>` before `<tr class="beachLogo">` is missing a `</td>`

Fix those issues and see if you get better results in Outlook.